# Copy sheet to a new workbook with name of the sheet + cell name

Tags: excel, vba

I want to name a new workbook with the name of a copied sheet and a cell value.

I'm looking for the name of the sheet "Activites" + cell A11 to register in the folder.

As this sheet with data needs to be saved every week. How can I add a cell reference to the saved sheet? (If not, a message appears saying this file already exists.)

```vb
Sub Export_Activities()

Dim worksheet_list As Variant, worksheet_name As Variant
Dim new_workbook As Workbook
Dim saved_folder As String

saved_folder = "C:\Users\Maz\Desktop\DIMSO\Archives_Activites\"
worksheet_list = Array("Activites")

For Each worksheet_name In worksheet_list
    On Error Resume Next
   
    Set new_workbook = Workbooks.Add
   
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheet_name).Copy new_workbook.Worksheets(1)
   
    new_workbook.SaveAs saved_folder & worksheet_name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
    new_workbook.Close False
Next worksheet_name

MsgBox "L'exportation est complète, N'oubliez pas de renommer la feuille exportée.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should save the workbook with the Worksheet name + the value of the Cell A11:

```
Sub Export_Activities()
    Dim worksheet_list As Variant, worksheet_name As Variant
    Dim new_workbook As Workbook
    Dim saved_folder As String
    Dim workbookname As String '<----- Added line.
    
    saved_folder = "C:\Users\Maz\Desktop\DIMSO\Archives_Activites"
    worksheet_list = Array("Activites")
    
    For Each worksheet_name In worksheet_list
        On Error Resume Next
    
        Set new_workbook = Workbooks.Add
    
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheet_name).Copy new_workbook.Worksheets(1)
        
        workbookname = worksheet_name & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheet_name).Range("A11").Value '<----- Added line.
        
        new_workbook.SaveAs saved_folder & workbookname & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51 'worksheet_name changed for workbookname
        new_workbook.Close False
    Next worksheet_name

    MsgBox "L'exportation est complète, N'oubliez pas de renommer la feuille exportée.", vbInformation

End Sub
```